# Static images with apostrophe-cms

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I've read the [Guide for pushing assets](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/getting-started/pushing-assets#including-webfonts-images-and-other-assets) and it didn't help me. I want to change the arrow of a dropdown that I have on my code.

```
<div class="filter-dropdown">
    <select class="filter-select select-borders-styles">
        <option value="newest">Newest First</option>
        <option value="oldest">Oldest First</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is the less code:

```
.filter-dropdown{
      [...]

        .filter-select{
            background: url('/modules/my-module/public/img/my-image.png') no-repeat 96% 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 240px;
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 19px;
            -webkit-appearance: none;  /*Removes default chrome and safari style*/
            -moz-appearance: none;   /*Removes default style Firefox*/
            color: #0167C2;  

            select{
                [..]
            }
        }

        .select-borders-styles{
           [...]
        }
}
```

I've seen that I have to add the image on /my-module/public/img/my-image.png, I've added it and I add the url with the correct path in the less file, but it doesn't work.

If I add in de index.js file like when yo add a .less this code:

```
    self.pushAssets = function() {
      superPushAssets();
      self.pushAsset('img', 'options_arrow', { when: 'always' });
    };
```

it displays this error:

```
    /home/kalia/Escritorio/leo-newsletter/newsletter/node_modules/apostrophe/index.js:75
        throw err;
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fs' of undefined
    at Object.self.push (/home/kalia/Escritorio/leo-newsletter/newsletter/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/index.js:497:67)
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pushAsset` method is for CSS files and javascript, not images. So that code will not work. But, you don't need it. It's only for combining things into bundles for delivery as a single file, which is not a feature you need for your image.

If you have an image at `lib/modules/mymodulename/public/my.png`, then you can reference it with this URL: `/modules/mymodulename/my.png`

This works because Apostrophe copies or symlinks the `public` folders of your modules to `/modules/...` at startup, depending on the OS.

Note that the URL does *not* contain `/public` or `/lib`. Just `/modules/mymodulename/...`. You can have an `images` subdir if you want, in which case it would be `/modules/mymodulename/images/my.png` (that is, everything that comes *after* `public` in the filename does need to be in the URL).